# how to secure frontend iframe authentication?

Tags: authentication, security, iframe, jwt

I am at a point again where I need to reconsider my approach for authenticating users to my iFrame.

So let me give some context. I have a chatbot service, this service is meant to be embedded into my user's website. Therefore I need an identifier for that user, so that I can load the chatbot's iFrame with the necessary data for my user, creating a session under the name of my user for the enduser using the chatbot.

And so I wend on to build a server to server authentication method, in which The user's backend would communicate with mine using an API-Key with https to securely issue these sessions to the enduser to start talking with the chatbot. The server to server method is awesome for security, as this means as long as my user is the only one in possession of his api key, then only that user is able to initiate a chatbot session using his data, as well as incrementing his usage meters.

But this resulted in increased complexity and also came at the expense of user experience. The Server to Server approach requires the iFrame to support a multitude of backend infrastructure. So for example wix requires using http functions. There are backends that work with python on flask, others with nodejs. This Server to Server method requires the user to also make an endpoint on his server, which is something I would rather avoid, but I am not sure if requiring new endpoints from your user is normal or standard or not.

And then I had to go reevaluating to the frontend approach. So I use Firebase, a google service for managing login and authentication of users. Firebase also uses frontend authentication, where my credentials are stored on the frontend. This should work because google uses domain whitelisting and other various security measures. (Am I stupid for leaving my firebase credentials on frontend???? or does this make sense xD)

And so I thought I could also use a similar identifier for my user. He would then whitelist his website's domain allowing that identifier to only be accessed from that whitelisted website. The question now, is this a secure approach??? what can I also use as security measures? Can't someone impersonate the user's domain let's say myuserA.com and call the chatbot's IFrame from his fake website? Due to the identifier now being in the frontend. If someone were able to impersonate my user's domain, what use would that bring him? Let's say the impersonator works on music, whereas myuserA works on sport. The IFrame would still always answer with the data for sports from myuserA. It would act like free marketing to myuserA, still would cost more money tho, but still it effectively advertises myuserA's products and services. How realistic are these risks? Is the extra work for making the IFrame able to support multiple backend infrastructures a better approach? What else can I do to make the frontend approach more secure? As that approach seems quite simpler and user-friendly.

Notes:

The Chatbot's IFrame only has access to PUBLIC data already available online.
The session is going to be issued in form of a jwt, which are short lived and regulated by the server.
Thank you for reading this :D. I am still inexperienced in these aspects but I am willing to learn more about it.

Comment: Pure text questions are possible on Stackoverflow but they won't attract much attention. Also your question is a but long. I would recommend to edit and rewrite it and focus more on the core problem you have.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your feedback! Alright then, i'll be editing it now :D